# Занесение строки в массив

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Как занести введённую с клавиатуры строку в массив?

```
args = new String[3];
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String from = sc.nextLine();
args[0] = "aaa";
args[1] = "bbbb";
args[2] = "00.00.2015";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ideone.com/z9wBNL

```
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] a = new String[3];
        String str;

        for (int q=0; q<a.length && (str=reader.readLine())!=null; ++q) {
            a[q] = str;
        }

        System.out.print(a[1]);
    }
}
```